# Show tags under their own specific tab

Tags: tags, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating a tag system on my website. So far it's all working great. But now I wish to create a page that shows all my tags under their own tab like you have with a portfolio page.

Example: http://www.don-zalmrol.be/tags?tag=Electronics

My page already displays the tags for a specific tag under it's own tab (i.e. electronics), but as you might guess I wish to populate the other tags in their respective tab as well.

So in short you land a view that displays the tag you've selected, but on the same page you can see the others as well.

Anybody has any idea how I can do this? I don't think I'm far away from the solution as I can already load the projects for specific tags under it's own tab. Now I only need to populate the remaining tabs with the tags!

Thanks!

This is my code so far:

http://pastebin.com/jwGW0NKZ

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{ 
    var portfolio = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllContentTags().OrderBy(t => t.Text); 
    var tagList = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllContentTags().OrderBy(t => t.Text); 
    string tag = Request.QueryString["tag"];

    if (!tag.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        var publishedContent = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetContentByTag(tag);

        if (publishedContent.Count() > 0)
        {
            @* Show title *@
            <div class="media contact-info wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                <center>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2>Tags</h2>
                        <p>Browse content by tag</p>
                    </div>
                </center>

                <br />

            </div>


            @* Show tag titles in tabs *@
            <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">

                <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter="*">All tags</a></li>

                @foreach (var tags in tagList)
                {
                    <!-- Create a selected tag -->
                    if(@tags.Text == @tag)
                    {
                        <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter=".@tag">@tag</a></li>
                    }

                    @* Show all other tags *@
                    else
                    {
                        <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".@tags.Text">@tags.Text</a></li>
                    }
                }

            </ul>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="portfolio-items">

                    @* Start picture content *@
                    @foreach (var tags in tagList)
                    {
                        @* Put selected tag in the right tag tab *@
                        if(@tags.Text == @tag)
                        {
                            @* Show tag content *@
                            foreach (var item in publishedContent.OrderByDescending(i => i.CreateDate))
                            {                   
                                <div class='portfolio-item @tag col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3'>
                                    <div class="recent-work-wrap">

                                        @* IF the project has a picture *@
                                        @if(item.HasValue("pictureOfTheProject"))
                                        {
                                            var featureImage = Umbraco.TypedMedia((int)item.GetPropertyValue("pictureOfTheProject")); 
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="@featureImage.GetCropUrl(250, 250)" alt='@item.GetPropertyValue("titleOfTheProject")' /> 

                                            <div class="overlay">
                                                <div class="recent-work-inner">

                                                    <h3><a href="@item.Url">@item.GetPropertyValue("titleOfTheProject")</a></h3>

                                                    <a class="preview" href="@featureImage.GetCropUrl(250, 250)" rel="prettyPhoto">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                        @* Else when the project doesnt have a picture, show default one *@
                                        else
                                        {
                                            var noImage = "http://www.don-zalmrol.be/media/1440/no_image_available.png";
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="@noImage.GetCropUrl(250, 250)" alt="No image" />

                                            <div class="overlay">
                                                <div class="recent-work-inner">

                                                    <h3><a href="@item.Url">@item.GetPropertyValue("titleOfTheProject")</a></h3>

                                                    <a class="preview" href="@noImage.GetCropUrl(250, 250)" rel="prettyPhoto">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View
                                                    </a>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            }
                        }

                        @* Put the other tags under there own tab *@
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    @* End dynamic tags *@

                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @* No content matching the tag? *@
        else
        {
            <p>There isn't any content matching that tag.</p>

            @Html.Partial("TagList")
        }
    }

    @* Show the tag list with amount *@
    else
    {
        @Html.Partial("TagList")
    }

}
```

EDIT 27-03-2016

Ok so I now know that I need to play around with my tag query or use the IEnumerable. But I can't seem to find it out how I can do this without breaking the code...

@* Get all tags and order them by name *@
var tagList = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllContentTags().OrderBy(t => t.Text);

@* Get requested tag *@
string tag = Request.QueryString["tag"];

@* Show all content by requested tag *@
var publishedContent = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetContentByTag(tag);

Above are the pieces of code that list all the tags I have in a var, gets the name from the URL (i.e. Electronics) and one that then displays all content that matches said queried tag.

So in short I need to change the last part of the TagQuery to list all content that has a tag and then filter it out by the querystring to display them in their own category.

But how can list all tagcontent?

Cheers,

Don

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on line 76 of the pastebin where you loop through the published content, which is already filtered by the selected tag. Because of this, only content with the selected tag ever gets written to the template.

What you need to do is use the loop on line 70 where you're looping through all tags. The jQuery plugin you're using will handle the filtering by using the CSS class you add on line 78. You can get rid of the loop on line 76.

For clarity, I would also change the

```
@foreach (var tags in tagList)
```

to

```
@foreach (var item in tagList)
```

since the foreach is producing a single tag rather than plural "tags" as your code insinuates. This has the added bonus of allowing you to keep the rest of your code the same once you remove the loop on line 76.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for getting back to me. I've tried doing it, but now I receive an error on line 79. http://pastebin.com/SyqQ6Z70 It is stating the following " CS1928: 'Umbraco.Web.Models.TagModel' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and the best extension method overload 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.HasValue(Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent, string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @DonZalmrol If you want to use those methods, either extend the TagModel class, adding them, or cast the collection to IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>

Comment: How could I use this IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> best in my code?